# SQL Join for exporting member details

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, inner-join

I have two tables that have member data in them, the reason for this is that I am using Expression Engine and by default it has a standard member data table that includes Email etc. To add custom fields to my register I had to create a secondary table with additional information. I now need to do an export of all member details in a specific order.

Could anyone help me, I have an email table field from the exp_members table that I need to join to the exp_member_data table. I would like the email field added as the third field in the join, this is for an export of member details. I hope this is clear, thanks.

Comment: Can you please give us the structure of your tables + some example data?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I havent tried much, I was able to do simple export using the following query "SELECT * FROM exp_member_data" . This exports all information obviously from that table.  Whats the best way to give u the structure of the table. It wont let me add screen shots

Comment: you can make a sample in [FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) and share the link..

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8da99 - Never used SQLfiddle before. Hopefully this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which fields you want to select and what there names are, but basic structure is as below:

```
SELECT 
 exp_members.field_so_and_so,
 exp_members.field_so_and_so,
 exp_members.email,
 ...,
 exp_members_data.field_so_and_so,
 ...
FROM exp_members
INNER JOIN exp_members_data ON exp_members.email = exp_members_data.email
ORDER BY exp_members.field_so_and_so, ...
```

Comment: The exp_member_data table where we are creating the join has 25 fields in total, would I have to write out all 25 on the ORDER BY line?

Comment: No just the ones you want to sort by. In the select you can use exp_members.* to select all fields.